# How do I get an entire row in a single line?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have this code:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
freq_matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(df.Text).todense()
print freq_matrix
```

df.text contains tweets.A bag of words is created in alphabetical order and frequency matrix is the occurrences of these words in each tweet.

When I print the matrix after every 37th column a new line is added.
like this-

```
[[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]
...
```

Whereas I thought that for a single row all the columns will be in a single line. How can I get them in a single line?

Comment: did you try numpy @kavya Sharma

Comment: No, can you help me out with that?

Comment: need to explain your question properly and what things you tried @kavya